# Entity Framework: как использовать один контекст на все приложение

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть форма с гридом. Данные редактируются с помощью формы для редактирования записи. Как вызвать сохранение изменений в форме для редактирования.
Делаю так
главная форма:

```
class UserForm : Window
{
    TemplateBaseConneciton context;
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        context = new TemplateBaseConneciton ();
    }

    private void AddButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditUserForm form = new EditUserForm();
        form.Context = context;
        form.DataContext = MainGrid.DataContext;
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}

class EditUserForm : Window
{
    TemplateBaseConneciton context;
    public TemplateBaseConneciton Context
    {
        get { return context; }
        set { context = value; }
    }
    private void AcceptButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Изменения не сохраняются.

Comment: Чё-то не то. Вы уверены, что дали правильный код? Именно `Conneciton`, а не `Connection`? Как у вас получилось присвоить `DBEntities` в `TemplateBaseConneciton`?

Comment: Исправил...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ошибку. На Window_Loaded создавался новый контекст. %)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону IoC-контейнеров.